# Mouseevent handler is not working in the vue-mapbox package

Tags: vue.js, mouseevent, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to make my map zoom in to a cluster when the user clicks the cluster. The map is built with mapbox gl and Vue-Mapbox. I understand I can use the getClusterExpansionZoom() method to do so, but the first step is detecting which cluster the user clicked on. My @click handler does not detect clicks. Why not? What must I change? Cheers

```
<template>
<div>
<MglMap>
      <MglGeojsonLayer
        class="mgl-clusters-layer"
        layerId="clustersLayerId"
        :layer="clustersLayer"
        :source="clustersSource"
        sourceId="clustersSourceId"
        @click="clickedCluster()"
      />
</div>
</template>
```

These variations also do not work...

1. @click="clickedCluster"
2. @map-click="clickedCluster()"
3. @click.prevent="clickedCluster"

Here is my event handler...

```
  methods: {
    clickedCluster() {
      console.log("clicked cluster");
    }
  }
```

Here is the definition of the clustersSource object

```
 clustersSource: {
    type: "geojson",
    cluster: true,
    clusterRadius: 25,
    clusterProperties: { sum: ["+", ["get", "docCount"]] },
    data: {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: []
    }
  },
```

data.features array of simple geojson points

Here is the definition of clustersLayer...

```
clustersLayer: {
    id: util.getRandomValue(),
    type: "circle",
    filter: ["has", "point_count"],
    paint: {
      "circle-color": "#6a0dad",
      "circle-opacity": 0.4,
      "circle-stroke-color": "#6a0dad",
      "circle-stroke-width": 1,
      "circle-radius": [
        "step",
        ["get", "sum"],
        8,
        100,
        10,
        1000,
        12,
        10000,
        14,
        100000,
        16,
        1000000,
        18
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
  //Make map zoom to a districts cluster when user clicks the cluster
  this.map.on("click", "clustersLayerId", function(e) {
    var features = $this.map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
      layers: ["clustersLayerId"]
    });
    $this.map.easeTo({
      center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,
      zoom: $this.map.getZoom() + 1
    });
  });
```

You also have to specify the id in the clustersLayer object...

```
clustersLayer: {
    id: "clustersLayerId",
    type: "circle",
    filter: ["has", "point_count"],
    paint: {
      "circle-color": "#6a0dad",
      "circle-opacity": 0.4,
      "circle-stroke-color": "#6a0dad",
      "circle-stroke-width": 1,
      "circle-radius": [
        "step",
        ["get", "sum"],
        8,
        100,
        10,
        1000,
        12,
        10000,
        14,
        100000,
        16,
        1000000,
        18
      ]
    }
  },
```